# It is possible to use realloc on char** in one line?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, realloc

I really do not know if it is the right title for my question, but I will try to explain my problem :

I'm working on a program which search all string permutes and saves those string in a `char**` array.

Everything looks fine, but the program takes too much time too finish and this happens because of `realloc` calls which are too many and takes too much time. I am talking about 13700 calls here:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < SIZE_2D; i++ ){ // SIZE_2D == 13700
    multi[i] = calloc(LINELENGTH, sizeof(char));
}
```

It is possible to call realloc on `char**` in a single call ?
Like the example here :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int *arr;
    unsigned int row = 5, col = 10;

    arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * row * col);
    if(arr == NULL){
        printf("Error, malloc\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    free(arr);
}
```

This is the working code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE_2D 13700
#define LINELENGTH 8

void swap (char *x, char *y);
void permute(char *arr, char *ptr, size_t i, size_t n);
int compare(const void *a, const void *b);
void resizeBuffer ( char **arr, size_t length );
void resultFound( char **multi, char *buffer, size_t length );

//char multi[20240][50] = {0};

int main(void){
    char str[] = "abcdefg";
    char *arr = calloc(100000, sizeof(char));
    char *multi[14000];
    //char **multi = calloc(10240, sizeof(char*));

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < SIZE_2D; i++ ){
        multi[i] = calloc(LINELENGTH, sizeof(char));
    }

    permute( arr, str, 0, strlen( str ) );
    resizeBuffer ( &arr, strlen( arr ) + 1 );

    resultFound(multi, arr, strlen( arr ) );
    free( arr );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < SIZE_2D; i++ ){
        free(multi[i]);
    }
}

void resultFound( char **multi, char *buffer, size_t length ){
    printf("ARR LENGTH = %zu\n", length);
    size_t i = 0;
    char *ptr = buffer;
    size_t p = 0;
    size_t a = 0;

    char *tmp = calloc(length + 1, sizeof(char));
    size_t count = 0;

    while ( i < length ){
        if ( ptr[i] == '\n' ){
            if ( count != 0){
                //printf("Line Found! <-> Line Length = %zu <-> TMP = %s\n",count, tmp);
                strcpy(multi[a++], tmp);
                memset(tmp, 0, length);
                count = 0;
                p = 0;
            }else{
                //printf("Empty Line Found, Ignore it\n\n");
            }
        }else{
            count++;
            tmp[p++] = ptr[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    for (size_t l = 0 ; l < a ; l++ ){
        printf("Multi[%zu]\t=  %s\n",l , multi[l]);
    }

    free(tmp);
}

void swap (char *x, char *y){
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void permute(char *arr, char *ptr, size_t i, size_t n){
    size_t j;
    static char prev[80] = "";
    if (i == n){
        if (strcmp(prev, ptr)) {
            strcat (arr, ptr);
            strcat (arr, "\n");
            strcpy(prev, ptr);
        }
    }else{
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
        {

            swap( (ptr + i), (ptr + j) );
            permute(arr, ptr, i+1, n);
            swap( (ptr + i), (ptr + j) );
        }
    }
}

void resizeBuffer ( char **buffer, size_t length ){
    *buffer = realloc(*buffer, (length)* sizeof(char) );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the link between your code and your question, you only call realloc one time.

Comment: Don't call realloc then. Simply allocate "large enough" for each string, and if you get a string length that goes beyond "large enough", and only then, call realloc. To always dynamically allocate the exact amount of bytes needed is a manual, heavy optimization to minimize memory consumption. This comes at the expense of execution speed. If you need execution speed, then optimize for speed and not for memory consumption.

Comment: @PaulR Yes, I think that is what I need. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @xing on modern operating systems `calloc` is the same as malloc; and faster than doing malloc followed by setting some values

Comment: @M.M I seriously doubt that, how should that work? The OS has to clear freshly mapped pages anyway, that's correct. But how can you rely on that mechanism in the calloc/malloc-case?

Comment: The problem with realoc is, that I need it because the main string is between 2 and 7 length. I cannot predict which input comes from the user.

Comment: @Michi The difference between 2 and 7 bytes is not worth worrying about. The memory block returned by the `malloc` family is likely to be on an 8-byte boundary anyway.

Comment: Assuming that the code works correctly, you might want to write up your samples in a more-complete fashion and ask for critique over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Comment: @TobySpeight I only need an answer to my question and that’s all. The code I showed was just for clarification and not to be fixed. I only need to know if I can call realloc in one line or not. That’s it.